# Functions keep returning 0

Tags: c, pointers

I have a three functions one inside another, they use the same inputs as it shown in my code, every time I printf the inputs after I pass the three functions I get a "0" as a value.

I tried to delete the "free()", as I thought it's because of it that my inputs get a 0 as values, but if I do, the code freeze.

```
char passcode[20];

void configuration(int **d, char *c) {
  *d = malloc(sizeof(int));
  **d = 1;

  readn(*d, c);

  return;
}

void readn(int *d, char *c) {
  *d = 2;

  configuration_SYS(d, c);


  return;
}

void configuration_SYS(int *d, char *c) {
  strcpy(c, "1234");
  *d = 3;

  return;
}

void main() {
  int *Timeout;

  configuration(&Timeout, passcode);

  printf("%d\n", *Timeout);
  printf("%s", passcode);
}
```

I expect to get a values different than 0 when I printf the two variables.
Timeout should equal  6 and passcode = "1234".

Comment: `d = malloc(sizeof(int));` changes the *local* pointer to a different memory location. Not that it makes much sense, as you pass a pointer to a variable with automatic storage duration

Comment: Thanks for reply, how I can keep the same memory location?

Comment: Just remove all the `malloc` and `free` calls in your code, they are completely unnecessary

Comment: What is `void configuration(...)` supposed to do? `char *mdp = malloc(sizeof(20)); mdp = "1234";` is a *Memory Leak*. When you assign `mdp = "1234";` you lose the address returned by `malloc` preventing that memory from ever being reached (or freed).

Comment: it take as input two variables and it put in them 2 values ( the time out and a passcode).

Comment: `printf("%d", Timeout);` outputs `Timeout` (which is initialized `0` by virtual of having *static storage duration*), `passcode` is not referenced in `void configuration(...)`

Comment: your code is such a mess. It doesn't even compile. you call `configuration_SYS` with 2 param but the function has 3 arguments

Comment: it was a mistake when I past it here, the code compile, the purpose of this code is to put a values in two global variables. I should get in Timeout a value = 6 and passcode ="1234"

Comment: Unless you are writing code for an embedded *Freestanding System* (without an operating system), your use of `main()` is incorrect, see [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1)

Comment: yes I'm using an NRF52.

Comment: I checked [but didn't double check], but I believe if you remove _all_ the `malloc` and `free` calls in your sub-functions, the values you set will get passed back to `main`. As, it is the values go to arrays/values that get freed before return. This is especially true for `d` and `c`. And, `mdp` does [pretty much] nothing as coded.

Comment: @CraigEstey It worked for Timeout I'm getting 6 but sadly not for passcode, Thanks a lot.

Comment: After removing `malloc/free`, in your inner functions, _none_ of them actually set/modify what `c` _points_ to (e.g.) `strcpy(c,"hello world");`. So, _one_ of them has to.

Answer (score 1):

- You do not need to use `malloc()` every time you use a pointer. `malloc()` allocates space for your use. **NOTE**: this space is not necessarily initialized (meaning that the data could be any value)
- There is no need to `return;` at the end of a void function. The closing brace will return for you.
- You call `configuration_SYS(char* abc, int* d, char* c)` with two arguments, yet the function takes three parameters.

As it is, I cannot compile this program. I'm not sure why it prints 0s for you. I would work on creating a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)